# How can I share my Google Scholar profile with selected people only?

Tags: google-scholar

In Google Scholar under the section:

My profile > Pencil symbol > Make my profile public

I have unchecked the option.

This has made my Google Scholar profile private. Now I want the ability to share my profile with few of my friends, not all. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably a profile can be public or private, not somewhere in between, so

> I want the ability to share my profile with [a] few of my friends

this isn't possible unless you adopt an ad hoc solution, e.g., you could save the page and share by email. (More sophisticated solutions exist, for instance, you could mirror the page somewhere and grant a few friends access to the mirror, but such a solution will be time consuming to deploy.)

Comment: Related: https://www.xkcd.com/2106/ With Google Scholar there are also two options, but its between 1 person (yourself) and a billion+. Go figure!

Comment: Any third party solution?

Comment: @BrianH in that meme it says 300 or billion. Here it's myself or billion of people. Come on, there is no way? Or at least a tracking mechanism?

Comment: I have posted this query in their help page. Here: https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general